# get NSData instead of NSXMLParser

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsxmlparser, afnetworking-2

I am uploading photo and thumb along with few parameters everything is working fine. On completion of request in `success` block I am receiving NSXMLParser as responseObject because I have specified acceptableContentTypes `text/xml`.

I am using CXMLParser so I need that in NSData or NSString format. Is it possible to do so ? I am unable to locate in documents.

```
NSData *imgData = [params objectForKey:@"imgData"];
NSData *imgThumbData = [params objectForKey:@"imgThumbData"];

_manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kAPIBaseURLString]];
_manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/xml"];
[_manager setResponseSerializer:[AFXMLParserResponseSerializer new]];
[_manager POST:kUploadMedia parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:imgData name:@"MediaFile" fileName:@"mediafile.png" mimeType:@"png"];
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:imgThumbData name:@"MediaThumbfile" fileName:@"mediafile_thumb.png" mimeType:@"png"];
} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSXMLParser *parser = (NSXMLParser*)responseObject;
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"error->%@",error.localizedDescription);
}];
```

Comment: Try change or, remove `responseSerializer`.

Comment: Thanks @iphonic it worked. I changed AFXMLParserResponseSerializer to AFHTTPParserResponseSerializer so getting the raw output from web service. Please add answer if you wish, I will accept :).

Comment: Yes added it as answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try change or, remove `responseSerializer`. You should add `AFHTTPParserResponseSerializer` as responseSerializer to get the raw data.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
NSData *dd=[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:responseObject options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
}
```